# Cors problem with .NET app and React despite cors configuration

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net

I'm building a backend using microsoft technologies for the first time and I'm having trouble getting my back-end to communicate with my front-end (React). The HTTP requests coming from Postman are succesful, so I doubt it is a problem with the build. I've been following tutorials and solutions on Stackoverflow, but I'm still getting the following message:

[CORS blocking error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52SSg.png)

Here is my Program.cs file, if it can help someone find the problem in my configuration:

```
var myAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var Configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<BlogContext>(options =>
{
   var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
   options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
});


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
   options.AddPolicy(name: myAllowSpecificOrigins,
       builder =>
       {
           builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials();

       });
}
);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                   options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                   {
                       ValidateIssuer = false,
                       ValidateAudience = false,
                       ValidateLifetime = true,
                       ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                       IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWTSecretKey"))
                       )
                   };
               });

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthService>(
   new AuthService(
       Configuration.GetValue<string>("JWTSecretKey"),
       Configuration.GetValue<int>("JWTLifespan")
   )
);

builder.Services
  .AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
       options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
   });
       


var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(myAllowSpecificOrigins);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();
   app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();


app.Run();
```

**EDIT**

I tried to allow all origins and got the following error (this is by calling localhost:5090 from client. With localhost:7090 the backend simply throw a network connection error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5090/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Comment: Hmm, it does look configured right.  Can you try allowing all origins, or anything else that opens it up more, till you are able to hit the endpoint?  Then work backwards re-applying the settings to find out what is causing the issue.

Comment: This is at the point I am. I allowed any origin in my policy configuration with the allowAnyOrigin() and still get CORS blocking. It seems the backend doesn't add the cors policies. I tried to add [EnableCors] notation to my endpoints in my controller file to no avail. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to add I got a different error now, I will edit my OP: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5090/api/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

Comment: Error message is very clear.  The site requires a new http header that is missing or is wrong.  It is possible that you ID in the header expired or you are using HTTP and the site now requires HTTPS (secure).

Answer (score 0):

It could potentially be a missing proxy setting on the front end. Without knowing how your front end is configured, it would be my guess. Please see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually) for instructions on how to set it up.

In my experience, I had to configure the setting manually through a setupProxy.js file (the instructions are also included in the link above)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue by following the recent doc from Microsoft on the subject (published 06/03/2022) and making a small tweak. It was a really simple solution and I hope it can help others in the future who have tried everything else :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I made three changes that made all the difference:

**1. Remove this line of code in Program.cs: app.UseHttpsRedirection();**

**2. Change**

```
 builder =>
       {
           builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
```

with

```
      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
```

**3. Add those two lines of code before app.UseCors:**

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
```

Comment: change 1 will cause big security concern if you ever wants to host your API to production where you would need to use HTTPS. your change no 2 does not have any impact its just name change. and in change 3, `app.usestaticfiles()` is only useful if your serving any static files from your api which doesn't seems to be case here.